# Netbeans 8 Debugger, how to use advanced formatter to see the variables values

Tags: debugging, netbeans

I really need for my work that the Netbeans debugger shows the variables data using a specific formatter.
I yet know how to use the basic formatter configuration from the options panel but in this case I need something more powerful.

In particular I have a class "ToView" that contains complex data structures. And another class called "FormatItCorrectly" with the method "format" that take as parameter a ToView class and returns the string that I want to see into the debugger.

```
public String format(ToView instance);
```

example:

```
String desiredString = FormatItCorrectly.format(toViewInstance);
```

Into the options panel -> Java -> Java Debugger  I added a new variable formatter called "Custom Formatter" and putted as class type "ToView", now what I have to put as code snippet into the field "Value formatted as a result of code snippet" ?

Answer (score 0):

On the Variable Formatter dialog in NetBeans, you need to enter the full package and class name for the class types you want to use custom formatting for.

So, for example, you would need to enter the "Class type" field as

```
com.myapp.ToView
```

assuming that your class is in the com.myapp package.

To make best use of the custom formatters in NetBeans, you should add a method onto your class ToView that will be called to format it.  This method can then invoke your formatter to generate the correctly formatted string.

So, you could make a method on your ToView class

```
public String format() {
  return FormatItCorrectly.format(this);
}
```

On the NetBeans variable formatter dialog, you would then specify the "Value formatted as a result of code snippet" to be:

```
format();
```

If you do not want to change your existing code to have a "format()" method, you can define a custom variable formatter to be invoked and return a correctly formatted object.  As in the following example, define the "Variable formatted as a result of code snippet" to be:

```
Class.forName("com.myapp.FormatItCorrectly");
return FormatItCorrectly.format(this);
```

You can see here that we have to use the Class.forName() method to load an instance of the FormatItCorrectly class into the debugger so that we can invoke the format() method of it.  The debugger can only call methods on classes that are in scope for formatting purposes, hence we need to ensure that the FormatItCorrectly class is in scope before we try to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me. I can not modify the source code of my company project. I would like that it is Netbeans Formatter to call FormatItCorrectly.format(this).
Here my colleagues use Eclipse and with it is possible to do that, but I would like to continue to use Netbeans..

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use variable formatters without modifying the source code of the object being debugged.

Comment: Thanks for your effort trying to solve my issue but also this code snippet does'n work for me.
Netbeans shows the following error: >"Class" is not a known variable in the current context.<

Comment: What did you type into the "Variable formatted as a result of code snippet" window?

Comment: Exactly your code snippet:

Class.forName("...

To give you an example, in eclipse the corresponding field ("Detail formatter code snippet defined for selected type:") contains:

com.myCompany.util.transform.FormatItCorrectly.format(this)

If I try to copy the same snippet to Netbeans it tells me
 >"com" is not a known variable in the current context.<

Comment: Is FormatItCorrectly.format() a static method.  If not, you will need to instance it first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66764/discussion-between-user2572526-and-dave).